# Connection timeout with SlashDB and Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, azure, slashdb

I've just installed SlashDB and connected to an Azure SQL DB successfully. Querying works and everything is fine. However, after a while, if I retry my previously working query, I get an error from SlashDB:

> 500 Internal Server Error (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', u'[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Write to the server failed (20006) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I'm not writing anything to the server, if that matters. But if I retry the query immediately, it works. My deep analysis (=guess) of this all is that the SQL Server terminates the idle connection. Now, I'd like SlashDB to retry when it fails, instead of returning error to the the client. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Azure SQL DB could be breaking connections due to either their redundancy limitations or the 30 minute idle.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/connections-and-sql-azure/

For performance reasons SlashDB does not establish a new connection for every request, but instead maintains a pool of connections.

MySQL, has a similar behavior, which is widely known (60 minutes idle timeout) and SlashDB actually has a logic to attempt reconnect. It should implement the same for all database types, but I need to confirm that with the development team (and fix if not the case).

In the meantime, you could either retry on the client side or send a periodic request for to avoid the timeout.